# How can I stop live-reload from executing on all files in Angular2 with angularCLI?

Tags: angular, webpack, livereload

**Environment:**

Angular 2.0.0 (Built via Angular CLI Beta 15 with Webpack)

**Issue:**

No way to turn off ***live-reload***. My application involves multiple areas where files need to be uploaded to the server, and/or be manipulated. Every time any of these actions occur, my application restarts, making it near impossible to test and continue development.

**Ideal Resolution:**

I really want to find a way to just disable the live-reloading. If this is not possible having used the AngularCLI, I need to know that its worth the time to rebuild the app without the CLI.

Pre-Webpack (with AngularCLI Beta 10) I used to be able to prevent this issue by running angular with this command:

From **package.json**

```
"angular-start": "ng serve --live-reload false",
```

This no longer works with the current version of Angular CLI.

**Update:**

The accepted answer is great except for one minor issue. For some reason when the app is launched in this way I can't load pages direct (i.e. http://172.16.1.213:4200 works, and if I navigate to my assets route I see http://172.16.1.213:4200/assets in the browser. But if I put http://172.16.1.213:4200/assets in the browser directly and hit enter I get "Cannot get assets" )

Also, if I upload a new image or video to the application when launched in this way, I can't see the image or video until refreshing.

My guess is that this is because of the nature of Webpack wanting to bundle all of these images/videos. I'm just confused how this could ever work in production when new files need to be uploaded all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple node app can serve Angular-cli /dist content.

1. Put following `server.js` in your project folder

   ```
   const port = 4000;
   const ip = "0.0.0.0";
   const dist = __dirname + '/dist';

   // Express
   const express = require('express');

   express()
       // Static content
       .use(express.static(dist))
       // SPA routing
       .get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'))
       // Start server
       .listen(port, ip, function () {
           console.log(ip + ':' + port);
       });
   ```
2. Install expressjs

   ```
   npm i express
   ```
3. Build your app*

   ```
   ng build
   ```
4. Start server

   ```
   node server.js
   ```

   - Repeat Step 3 each time finish up loading.

Comment: This is fantastic, one more thing though, how do I adjust so that I can reach this at the ip address of the machine from another box? Right now it only works at localhost.

Comment: Got it: using this: 
    .listen(port, "0.0.0.0", function () {
      console.log('Port: ' + port);
    });

Comment: @JasonPerr I updated your input into the answer too :D

Comment: any thoughts on the **Update** I posted to the question?

Comment: @JasonPerr Updated. But give me 30min, I have to add the SPA routing support in it.

Comment: @JasonPerr Please let me know if the updated server.js works or not.

Answer (score 0):

This flag is not implemented in webpack version, see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1755.

Comment: I saw that, but does that mean there is no way of doing this with any other flag? If so, I'm guessing that maybe the way I am trying to do this is wrong. There has to be a way of developing an app that involves uploading and changing media files that doesn't force a rebuild every single time right?